# Multiple page table segregation with Azure Forms Recognizer

Tags: azure, forms, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

This question is regarding Azure Forms Recognizer. We are working with scanned/non-scanned pdf's and tables inside the document.

If a table with line level items (rows and columns) are spanning across multiple pages in the pdf document, we usually need to create different tags for each page.

Is there a workaround to achieve the same without creating tags for each page? Suppose our training data has 2 pages of table, while at a later point of time production data might have n number of pages in tables. Thanks in advance !

We have reached till here, screenshot below:

[image: Form Recognizer Table segregation]

Comment: Adding on: Selecting "Row Dynamic" as table type limits the extraction to a single page only

Answer (score 1):

Form Recognizer does not yet support tables spanning multiple pages. In order not to label all pages you can split the PDF into pages prior to sending it to Form Recognizer and then post process them to a single table.

Comment: thanks for your reply, any other good tools/options apart from Azure Form Recognizer, Automation Anywhere IQ Bot, Abbyy Flexilayout that you can suggest to extract table/line level items and non-table data from scanned & non-scanned documents please ?

Comment: We can split and send the documents but these documents/invoices can have variable number of pages as well as we would not be sure which page would have these tables during training phase.